# Docker-Python script input error

Tags: python, docker, input, eof

I am new to Docker.I have a script named ApiClient.py.
The ApiClient.py script asks the user to input some data such as user's email,password,the input file(where the script will get some input information) and the output file(where the results will be output).I have used this Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /Users/username/Desktop/Dockerfiles
ADD . /Users/username/Desktop/Dockerfiles
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 80
ENV NAME var_name
CMD ["python", "ApiClient.py"]
```

1st Issue: I have used this WORKDIR and ADD because thats where the input and output files exist.Is it wrong to declare  these directories?

2n Issue: The script asks for the user to input some info such as the email and password.However when i run:

```
docker run -p 4000:80 newapp
```

I get the following error: 
username = ("Please enter your username")

EOFError:EOF when reading a line

Why am i geting this error?

Answer (score 7):

Use `docker run -i -t <your-options>`

So here, -i stands for interactive mode and -t will allocate a pseudo terminal for us.

Which in your scenario would be

```
docker run -p 4000:80 -it newapp
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks,i used: 
    docker run -ti newapp 
and it worked.
The probelm is that i cant define the input and the output file....

Comment: I see.. are you still getting the same error. You are not being able to username= interactively?

Comment: No i am not the error.Everything works when i enter my emal and username.The problem is that i dont know how to pass the input file as as argument from the container and where the output file will be created

Comment: @KonKyri, why not passing file paths as argument?

Comment: @aerokite That is what i am going to do.Can you provide me with an example?Both for the input and the output.

Comment: The file will be created inside container filesystem, the directory path you specify you can have it shared between container and host using -v host-dir:container-dir. These runtime arguments should work as well. But going with environment variables would be better for using your docker-file.

Answer (score 2):

Lets make some necessary files as example

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python
ADD . /python
WORKDIR /python

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "main.py"]
```

You want to run a script that will take two argument for input & output file

**main.py**

```
import sys
input_file = sys.argv[1]
output_file = sys.argv[2]
file = open(input_file, 'r') 
print(file.read())

file = open(output_file, 'w') 

file.write('Hello World')
```

Now build and run

```
$ docker build  -t test  .
$ docker run -it -v /tmp/python/:/python/data test data.txt data/output.txt
```

Your main.py will take input from `/python/data.txt` and write output in `/python/data/output.txt`

As `/python/data` is mounted into `/tmp/python/`, you will get `output.txt` in `/tmp/python/` in your local

Comment: Thanks for your help.I still have a problem with the files though.I have a folder named newappfiles on my desktop which contains: Dockerfile,requirements.txt and main.py. I use the commands you mentioned while being in the newappfiles folder.Where should i put the data.txt(input) and the output.txt(output) files?Inside the newappfiles or some other place?Then when using the command:
    $ docker run -it -v /tmp/python/:/python/data test data.txt data/output.txt
should I provide the full path of each file?

Comment: I can t understand where my input,output files will be.After the execution,the output.txt will be in the container?If yes,how will i access it?If no,where will it be in my computer?